# Write to Excel without scientifc notation using EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have a very straightforward question. I have a C# application which does some data processing and then outputs to an excel file using EPPlus. The problem is that some of my numbers are very long, for example, a data value could be something like `20150602125320`, which turns into `2.01506E+13` in the excel sheet. I am trying to avoid this. Converting the value to string works but I need them as numbers for further operations within excel. Anyone know any way I can keep the data in its original form without the scientific notation? Thank you!

Comment: Isn't the scientific notation conversion done by excel itself, not by the actual data in the columns?

Open the excel document, select your data, right click, and click "Format cells..." and choose Number and it will stop excel from changing your data to scientific notation. I'm not sure if EPPlus lets you do this cell formatting during document creation.

Comment: @bill I know I can do it through excel, but I am trying to fix the issue through EPPlus. I'm not sure either but there could be a way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the format string to match what you are looking for:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Big_Number_Format()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31124487/write-to-excel-without-scientifc-notation-using-epplus
    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\temp.xlsx");
    if (existingFile.Exists)
        existingFile.Delete();

    using (var package2 = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        var ws = package2.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = 20150602125320;
        ws.Cells[1, 2].Value = 20150602125320;

        ws.Cells[1, 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0";
        ws.Cells[1, 2].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00";
        package2.Save();
    }
}
```

If you want to see the a general list of the "built in" formats you see in the ribbon in excel you can see them here but you cant access them direct in you app since they are marked as `internal`:

https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/Style/XmlAccess/ExcelNumberFormatXml.cs#L62

```
/// <summary>
/// Id for number format
/// 
/// Build in ID's
/// 
/// 0   General 
/// 1   0 
/// 2   0.00 
/// 3   #,##0 
/// 4   #,##0.00 
/// 9   0% 
/// 10  0.00% 
/// 11  0.00E+00 
/// 12  # ?/? 
/// 13  # ??/?? 
/// 14  mm-dd-yy 
/// 15  d-mmm-yy 
/// 16  d-mmm 
/// 17  mmm-yy 
/// 18  h:mm AM/PM 
/// 19  h:mm:ss AM/PM 
/// 20  h:mm 
/// 21  h:mm:ss 
/// 22  m/d/yy h:mm 
/// 37  #,##0 ;(#,##0) 
/// 38  #,##0 ;[Red](#,##0) 
/// 39  #,##0.00;(#,##0.00) 
/// 40  #,##0.00;[Red](#,##0.00) 
/// 45  mm:ss 
/// 46  [h]:mm:ss 
/// 47  mmss.0 
/// 48  ##0.0E+0 
/// 49  @
/// </summary>
```

Comment: @petelids - Sorry about repeating your response - you won by a minute :)

Comment: No worries @Ernie - looks like I should have taken the extra minute to realise sparta93 didn't want decimal places :). Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `Numberformat` on the cell. In the underlying XML the `NumFmtId` you need to set is `1`.

I can't see a way that you can set the format Id directly, instead you need to set the format string. The [documentation here](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/EPPlus/EPPlus/ExcelNumberFormatXml/P/NumFmtId) lists (some of ) the mappings between the Id's and format strings. In your case it looks like you need `"0"`:

```
private static void WriteExcelFile(string path)
{
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage())
    {
        var workbook = package.Workbook;
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        var cell = worksheet.Cells["A1"];

        cell.Value = 20150602125320;

        cell.Style.Numberformat.Format = "0";

        //DefaultColWidth just set so you don't end up with #######
        //this is not required
        worksheet.DefaultColWidth = 20;
        package.SaveAs(new System.IO.FileInfo(path));
    }
}
```

Comment: using `0.00` was giving me `20150602125320.00` instead of `20150602125320`. Using `cell.Style.Numberformat.Format = "0";`  worked for me

Comment: Sorry @sparta93 - I didn't read it carefully enough to see that you wanted no decimal places. I'll update the answer to match the question better. Thanks.